# Isoperimetric problem on a generic surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, calculus-of-variations

In the plane, fixed two points, the curves that minimize the length  are straight lines, i.e curves with zero curvature. In the plane, fixed an area, the curves that minimizes length are circles, i.e. curves with constant non-zero curvature. On a surface, fixed two points, the curves that minimize the length  are geodesics, i.e curves with zero geodetic curvature. My question is

> On a surface, fixed an area, are the curves that minimize length the ones with constant non-zero geodesic curvature?

Comment: Constant (nonzero) geodesic curvature, yes.

Comment: Is this valid globally or only locally ?

Comment: Assuming the question makes sense, it's a first variation computation, so it seems to me it should hold whenever you have a solution, i.e., a candidate optimal curve bounding the given area.

Comment: I was thinking about this problem on a torus: I could always bound an area bewteen two meridian circles (that have geodesic curvature zero) but this shape is not locally euclidean (it's a cylinder). Now, maybe this is not the least-length boundary, but I just wanted to know if the result you mentioned was valid also for this "global situation", where we can minimize thanks to the twisting of the manifold

Comment: @TedShifrin Recently I was thinking about this problem on a cylinder. The cilynder is isometric to the plane, so the curves with constant non-zero geodesic curvature are "curved circles", right? But then, if we take a very big area, there exists no such "circle" that bounds it. Moreover, if you take two geodesics (orthogonal to cylinder axis as viewed in R3), they can bound as-big-as-we-want area and have always they same lenght ($4\pi$)! We can do better? Because otherwise... these have _zero_ geodesic curvature!

Comment: (moreover, why should it be non-zero? Lagrange multipliers method do not require that $\lambda$ is non-zero!)